# SQLDeveloper import multiple stored procedures or global replace

Tags: replace, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have exported all of my Stored Procedures with sql Developer (Oracle IDE  18.4.0.376.1900.)
Example, I have
v_link = '**http**://.....'

I have changed it in the exported SP to
v_link = '**httpS**://...'

How can I **import these stored procedures to overwrite** what I have in sqlDeveloper?

Or How can I do a **global replace** in ALL of my stored procedures in SqlDeveloper ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load those stored procedures (i.e. scripts you saved) into SQL Developer's Editor and execute them as a script. Doing so, you'll "overwrite" previous versions (which use **http**) and create new ones (with **https**).